# mysql user agent logging

Tags: php, mysql, database

Trying to do a couple of things, and I'm getting a bit stuck.

I've got the following code:

```
    <?php 
    $con=mysqli_connect("SERVERNAME","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DB");
    // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
           echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        } 
     $UserAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

     $query = "SELECT PID FROM `UserAgents` WHERE `UserAgent` = \"$UserAgent\"";

     //If User agent exists, get the record and update it by one
     //If it doesn't exist, create the record and set the value to 1.


      ?>
```

I'm trying to log how many different user agents are accessing a particular set of resources, as I want to make sure it's optimized for my biggest consumer group. So I'm trying to count how many different UA's access, as opposed to logging each one separately.

I'm getting hung up on extracting the value from the table (the PID for). I've attempted to look at the syntax in the PHP manual, but it's just not sticking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can check how to check for browser  http://dotclear.placeoweb.com/post/group-http-user-agent-sql  and  http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't go into too much detail on how to prepare and select data from a database, as you should find plenty of information on how to use mysqli to do that elsewhere (such as the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).)

I would however suggest looking into the `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax which essentially does the following ([documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html))

1. Attempts to insert a row into the database
2. If the insert fails because an existing row with the same key exists...
3. Falls back to the UPDATE portion of the query

For example say you had the following table `fooagents` with a UNIQUE constraint on the user_agent column.

```
user_agent
count
```

Then a user with the UA `FooBrowser 1.0` browses your site and you execute the following query

```
INSERT INTO fooagents (user_agent, count)
  VALUES ('FooBrowser 1.0', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE fooagents SET count = count + 1
```

The first time you run this, the `INSERT` is ran and the values are inserted into a new row in the database. The second time a user with that UA visits your site and you run this same query, because you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `fooagents.user_agent` column, the `INSERT` will fail, and trigger the `UPDATE` to run on the row that contains that unqiue UA, thanks to the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` part of your query.

Comment: I ended up using the above suggestion without the "ON DUPLICATE KEY". I kept getting an SQL syntax error (perhaps not available in my version of MYSQL? So, I'd try to insert with a value of 0, ignore the error if the record already existed, and then update the count. Thanks again for your help!